# Simple program needs 3x more time in C#

Tags: java, c#, performance

I have written a simple "benchmark" to compare performances in same cases - in Java and C#. In Java the program needs about 2,2s to complete (ran multiple times), in C# it needs 7,4s (ran multiple times).

Software used: Windows, Java (JDK 10), C# (.NET Framework 4.6.1)

Isn't CSharp's runtime jitting, or why is Java that times faster?

The program in Java:

```
Dummy[] dummies = new Dummy[100000000]; // Dummy = empty class

var timer = new Timer();
timer.start();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    dummies[i] = new Dummy();
}

timer.stop();
System.out.println(String.format("Elapsed time: %sms", timer.millis(2)));
```

And in C#:

```
Dummy[] dummies = new Dummy[100000000]; // Dummy = empty class

var timer = new Timer();
timer.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    dummies[i] = new Dummy();
}

timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0}ms", timer.Millis(2));
```

The Timer class in Java:

```
public class Timer {
    private long startTime, stopTime;

    public void start() {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        stopTime = startTime;
    }

    public void stop() {
        stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public double millis() {
        return stopTime / 1e6 - startTime / 1e6;
    }

    public double millis(int decimals) {
        double factor = Math.pow(10.0, decimals);
        return Math.round(millis() * factor) / factor;
    }
}
```

And in C#:

```
public class Timer
{
    private double startTime, stopTime;

    public void start()
    {
        startTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks).TotalMilliseconds;
        stopTime = startTime;
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        stopTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    public double Millis()
    {
        return stopTime - startTime;
    }

    public double Millis(int decimals)
    {
        return Math.Round(Millis(), decimals);
    }
}
```

Comment: In C# use the Stopwatch class to measure timings

Comment: well - use a profiler. Could be the bytecode, a JIT compiler not yet kicking in, excessive allocation of additional memory, anything. Impossible to say from just the code.

Comment: @Steve I had to intention to use a very similiar codebase, so you could compare without hesitating.

Comment: This sort of benchmark is relatively pointless. Do you often need to create 100 million objects and store references to them in an array? There are all kinds of things that could be at work here, particularly in terms of memory management, many of which probably aren't representative of real applications.

Comment: You will also normally run out of memory before getting close to creating 100 million objects

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Not on a machine with a fair amount of memory, if the class is reasonably small in terms of fields. At 16 bytes per object it's only ~1.5GB.

Comment: the array only stores references so that's 4 bytes per item on 32bit build and 8 bytes on 64bit build @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: The array isn't storing the objects - it's storing the references. So in a 64-bit CLR/JVM, that would be ~750MB, well under the 2GB limit. (And I believe that limit can be configured away in some situations anyway.) I've just run this with 6 `int` fields in `Dummy`, and it was still fine (taking ~4.5GB of memory). No problem.

Comment: In the c# code, you have a typo - should not compile: Is it `millis()` or `Millis()`?

Comment: Are you running this in `Release` mode?

Comment: Micro-benchmarks like this are almost always misleading.  You should concentrate on profiling and optimizing real production code.  There's tons of reason why Java might be faster.  For example, the JIT could notice that you are actually not doing anything with `Dummy` and optimize away all or most of the object creation.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yeah it's "Millis()" just typed the functions wrong

Comment: @RonBeyer I ran it with both, a difference of max 150ms.

Comment: Compiler will also act different based on your computer hardware / windows version / compiler version etc. It's not what you think.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I see the code newing up 100 millions `Dummy` objects. The fact that the array only holds references to those objects doesn't preclude that the objects themselves take up space too. The 100 million references point *somewhere*.

Comment: @InBetween: Yes, but that's not within a single object, so the limit Camilo was referring to doesn't apply. Yes, this code will take up quite a lot of memory - but there's no reason to expect us to *run out* of memory as Camilo was asserting, unless you really don't have much memory (for a modern system).

Comment: The major problem with this "benchmark" is that, even if a CLR developer looked at it and said "oh, I found why this is slower compared to the JVM" (because, say, objects take up more memory), it almost certainly gives us no obvious way or reason to speed it up, because the code itself performs no useful work. Optimizing this particular program would be easy -- but who's to say such optimizations would benefit real-world code and allocation patterns as well? This is true whether it takes 2 seconds, 7 seconds or 1 millisecond. This difference is significant, but not an order of magnitude.

Comment: To see whether the compiler leaves some of the objects away (because they are all equal) the `Dummy` object stores an `int` field of the current loop. After the `Timer` stops, all `Dummy` objects are written into a file with the help of the `toString()` method, which just returns the `int` as `string`. With this workaround, the compiler can't leave the objects away, because they are written into a file afterwards. The results: Are the same for java, but C# needs 8.1 seconds now.